# Determine the polynomials $P \in \mathbb{R}[X] $ such that : $X^n$ divides $X + 1 − P^2$.

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

please an idea to start the following exercise:

> Determine the polynomials $P \in \mathbb{R}[X] $ such that : $X^n$ divides $X + 1 − P^2$.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that $X^n$ divides $P^2-(1+X)$ if and only if $P^2-(1+X)=o(X^{n-1})$ as $X \rightarrow 0$. Without loss of generality, let's assume $P(0)=1$ (otherwise replace $P$ with $-P$) so that $\lim \limits_{X \rightarrow 0} (P+\sqrt{1+X})=2$. Therefore, $X^n$ divides $P^2-(1+X)$ if and only if $P-\sqrt{1+X}=o(X^{n-1})$ as $X \rightarrow 0$.
Consider the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+X}$: $$\sqrt{1+X}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}X^n=1+\frac{1}{2}X-\frac{1}{8}X^2+\frac{1}{16}X^3-...$$
It's not hard to see that $P-\sqrt{1+X}=o(X^{n-1})$ as $X \rightarrow 0$ if and only if the degree-less-than-$n$ terms in $P$ agree with the terms of the same degree in the series expansion. So for example, if you want $X^3$ to divide $P^2-(1+X)$, assuming that $P(0)=1$, you need $P-\sqrt{1+X}=o(X^2)$ as $X \rightarrow 0$, which means $P=1+\dfrac{1}{2}X-\dfrac{1}{8}X^2+X^3Q$ for an arbitrary polynomial $Q \in \Bbb{R}[x]$.